# Prefabs scaling change also the original prefab

Tags: unity, unityscript, prefabs

I want to work with a prefab as local and global variable? something like that.
So my question is how to change a prefab scale without affecting the original prefab.

Comment: Do you mean how to change the scale of an *instance* of a prefab, after you've `Instantiate`d a copy from the original asset? Try showing us the code you're using now so we can see what you're trying to do.

Comment: Also, I presume you're not really using the language UnityScript that Unity discontinued years ago? You're probably looking for answers in C#, so please use care when choosing the tags for your question, and read their descriptions.